Linux using Watchdog to monitor a folder, do not detect file event
I'm using Watchdog for monitoring a specific folder. if there is a .txt file created, it needs some processing. But now something very strange has happened: when I manually dragged a .txt file into this folder, it was detected, but when I used the command mv, it was not detected (I tried on_created and on_moved, but they were not detected).
I'm using AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu), and the monitored folder is EFS.
I tried on_created and on_moved, but they were not detected.
class FileCreationEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
def on_created(self, event):
    cron = CronTab(user='ubuntu')
    file_name = event.src_path.split('/')[-1]
    if file_name.endswith(".txt") and not file_name.startswith('temp_file'):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(event.src_path)
        input_file = open(event.src_path, "r")


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll need to include your code.  It's difficult to determine the issue without some sort of context.

Check events generated when you create or move a file in this directory, Watchdog use inotifywait to detect events so you can monitor events generated in your directory by :
inotifywait -m /path/to/your/directory

EFS itself as it's based on NFS the events generated are remote from the machine mounting the filesystem as inotify requires support from the kernel to work so watchdog can't detect this events but it depends on how you mount this volumes if that NFS share is mounted on host and then that mount point used as volume it works.

Thanks for your answer. I hadn't considered how to mount EFS.
I'm sorry for not mentioning it in the question, I also tried the inotifywait method, but it still didn't work.

Does inotifywait catch events while you are creating or moving files to this directory? As stated above NFS (as EFS) doesn't generate this events in the host mounting the filesystem as it's in kernel level (except when you double mountit as volume in containers )
